# PHP code to get client's IP address

Tags: php, apache

I have php code to get client's IP address. It's working fine with one http server (RHEL-4) but same code gives different IP in other server (CentOS).

What is causing this issue ?

The code is:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
function GetUserIP() {

if (isset($_SERVER)) {

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

    return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
GetUserIP();
}
?>
```

Comment: provide your code here

Comment: Well.. you never call `GetUserIP`?

Comment: what are you getting when you `echo GetUserIP();`?

Comment: Getting different IP from different server. Running same script on two web servers. On RHEL4 server getting proper IP but in CentOS getting different IP.